# systemd: decrypt luks device on access

Tags: encryption, mount, systemd, luks

I have an external drive with a LUKS-encrypted partition. As the device is an external USB device and I don't always need it, I only want to decrypt and automount on demand. I can easily automount the fileystem on the decrypted partition with `x-systemd.automount` in `/etc/fstab`. However, I cannot decrypt the partition on demand. I've tried two different approaches:

1. I added the line

   ```
   mnt-usb-crypt UUID=<UUID> /path/to/keyfile luks
   ```

   to `/etc/crypttab`. However, now the partition is *always* decrypted, even if I don't specify a mountpoint in `/etc/fstab`.
2. I changed `/etc/crypttab` and added the `noauto` option:

   ```
   mnt-usb-crypt UUID=<UUID> /path/to/keyfile luks,noauto
   ```

   Now, there is no systemd device at all, the expected `dev-mapper-mnt-usb.device` does not exist.

According to the manpage of `crypttab`, there is no option like `x-systemd.automount` for crypt devices.

Is there a possibility to configure systemd to decrypt the device only if it is accessed?

Comment: this is related to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/479261/how-to-automaticaly-mount-luks-partition-only-when-disk-is-plugged-in), but I want a systemd solution.

Comment: Nice first question. Unfortunately, I have a feeling that the answer is "no, that's not possible". A keyfile, `noauto` and a convenient alias (or similar) is probably about as close as you can get. You might however be able to configure the system to automount the file system when the LUKS device is opened -- that should be possible through udev. Not really what you are asking for, but it *does* remove at least one of the steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 in the question actually works, but you have to use the same names for the crypt device in both `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/fstab`.

`/etc/crypttab` looks as follows:

```
# <name>        <device>            <password>      <options>
mnt-usb-crypt   UUID=<device-uuid>  /path/to/key    luks,noauto
```

`/etc/fstab` looks as follows:

```
# <file system>             <dir>       <type>  <options>                             <dump>    <pass>
/dev/mapper/mnt-usb-crypt   /mnt/usb    btrfs   defaults,noauto,x-systemd.automount   0         2
```

Note that if you use the UUID of the decrypted filesystem instead of the path `/dev/mapper/mnt-usb-crypt`, then systemd cannot determine the device it has to decrypt. But if you use the device name as above, the device is automatically decrypted and mounted as expected.

A different solution would be to [explicitly specify a requirement](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#x-systemd.requires=) for the systemd crypt device.